# JavaScript find property is nested object for duplicated property names

Tags: javascript

I have a function that finds a property in a nested object by its name and returns its value.
The function I got from another question on this site and so far it has been working great.
I looks like this:

```
var _getPropertyValue = function (obj, field) {

    // Create a result
    var result = null;

    // If our object is an array
    if (obj instanceof Array) {

        // For each array item
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

            // Invoke our function for the current object
            result = _getPropertyValue(obj[i], field);

            // If we have a result
            if (result) {

                // Exit the loop
                break;
            }
        }

    // If we are an object
    } else {

        // For each property in our object
        for (var prop in obj) {

            // If our property matches our value
            if (prop == field) {

                // Return our value
                return obj[prop];
            }

            // If our property is an object or an array
            if (obj[prop] instanceof Object || obj[prop] instanceof Array) {

                // Invoke our function for the current object
                result = _getPropertyValue(obj[prop], field);

                // If we have a result
                if (result) {

                    // Exit the loop
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Return our result
    return result;
};
```

Now, I have thought that perhaps if I have an object like this:

```
{
    name: 'test',
    mode: 'default',
    settings: {
        mode: 'auto'
    }
}
```

With my function, I believe that it will find the first **mode** and then exit the function.
What I would prefer to do is specify the **field** parameter like this:

```
settings.mode
```

and for it to go straight to that place in my object and return the value.
Does anyone know if that can be done?

---

Dispite this being closed.
I answered this myself like this:

```
// Private function to get the value of the property
var _getPropertyValue = function (object, notation) {

    // Get all the properties
    var properties = notation.split('.');

    // If we only have one property
    if (properties.length === 1) {

        // Return our value
        return object[properties];
    }

    // Loop through our properties
    for (var property in object) {

        // Make sure we are a property
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {

            // If we our property name is the same as our first property
            if (property === properties[0]) {

                // Remove the first item from our properties
                properties.splice(0, 1);

                // Create our new dot notation
                var dotNotation = properties.join('.');

                // Find the value of the new dot notation
                return _getPropertyValue(object[property], dotNotation);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

---

I have further made this better like this:

```
// Private function to get the value of the property
var _getPropertyValue = function (obj, notation) {

    // Get our properties
    var properties = notation.split('.');

    // Use reduce to get the value of the property
    return properties.reduce(function (a, b) {

        // Return our value
        return a[b];
    }, obj);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    name: 'test',
    mode: 'default',
    settings: {
        mode: 'auto'
    }
};

var mode = obj.settings.mode;
```

Comment: that won't work. The **field** is being populated from a textbox.